# What is this kind of bracket called?

Tags: wood, metal, brackets, angle

I would ideally like this buy the below bracket, but I can't find any reseller.

Searching for `angle bracket oval adjustable hole` doesn't give anything similar, so I am guessing this kind of bracket have a particular name.

Does anyone know what it is called?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a slotted "L" bracket. It's available at most home stores.

Comment: Bracket or brace but definitely slotted I found one just like the photo using slotted bracket , brace came up with the exact match.